# Shoes building on OpenSUSE - Rake error

Tags: ruby, linux, rake, opensuse, shoes

I'm a beginner with Linux as well as with Ruby. My 32-bits laptop has OpenSUSE 13.2 installed, and I tried to install `shoes` on it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Linux). However, when I typed `rake`, it started to run and then shown this error message:

```
    gcc -I. -c -o shoes/effects.o -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -pthread -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i586-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/i586-linux-gnu -O  -DRUBY_1_9 -DSHOES_GTK -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  shoes/effects.c
    gcc -I. -c -o shoes/image.o -Wall -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -pthread -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i586-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/i586-linux-gnu -O  -DRUBY_1_9 -DSHOES_GTK -fPIC -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  shoes/image.c
    shoes/image.c: In function ‘shoes_surface_create_from_gif’:
       ^
    In file included from shoes/image.c:31:0:
    /usr/include/gif_lib.h:178:14: note: declared here
     GifFileType *DGifOpenFileName(const char *GifFileName, int *Error);
                  ^
    shoes/image.c: In function ‘shoes_surface_create_from_jpeg’:
    shoes/image.c:543:39: warning: variable ‘prevy’ set but not used         [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       int x, y, w, h, l, i, scans, count, prevy;
                                           ^
    shoes/image.c:543:32: warning: variable ‘count’ set but not used         [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       int x, y, w, h, l, i, scans, count, prevy;
                                    ^
    rake aborted!
    Command failed with status (1): [gcc -I. -c -o shoes/image.o -Wall -I/usr/i...]
    /home/Miotti/shoes/Rakefile:214:in `cc'
    /home/Miotti/shoes/Rakefile:222:in `block in <top (required)>'
    Tasks: TOP => default => build => linux:build => old_build => build_os => dist/shoes => dist/libshoes.so => shoes/image.o
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've no idea what I'm supposed to do now. I searched for this error, but I haven't found anything. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an updated Shoes3, you should try this one :
https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3
Instructions https://github.com/Shoes3/shoes3/wiki/5.0-Building-Shoes
Once all dependencies are met, it should be easy on Linux
(Binaries available here - Shoes 3.3.1 -  http://shoesrb.com/downloads/)

Comment: Actually there is one more problem. I have installed `shoes` successfully, but then I had to format my laptop. Now, when I type `rake`, it shows `unknown architecture`. Sometimes, it also says that it wasn't possible to find a `ruby-2.1.pc` file inside `pkg-config`. Any idea?

Comment: No, I did use RVM to install it. I did follow all steps from the link above.

Comment: which ruby did you install ?

Comment: I guess it was 2.2.4 (I don't have my laptop with me now).